# Equivalente italiano dell'espressione "early+name of day"

Tags: translation, english-comparison

Come si può rendere in italiano l'espressione "early+nome di giorno"?
Il contesto è "FIFA officially announced an investigation early wednesday"

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Non c'è molto meglio che ricorrere a una perifrasi: “la mattina di mercoledì”, “mercoledì, nelle prime ore della mattinata” (o qualcosa di più specifico se lo sapessimo, come “all'alba di”) e simili.

Answer (score 4):

L'equivalente più prossimo - benché probabilmente meno usato in italiano - credo sia l'espressione "nel primo mattino", "di primo mattino", "nelle prime ore di".

"Di primo mattino" è il più prossimo all'espressione originale ma ha un registro lievemente più arcaico.

Renderei la frase dell'OP con:

> *"Nelle prime ore di mercoledì la FIFA ha ufficialmente annunciato [l'apertura di] un'indagine"*

In alternativa (ma a mio parere meno preferibile per le questioni di registro menzionate sopra),

> *"Nel primo mattino di mercoledì la FIFA ha ufficialmente annunciato [l'apertura di] un'indagine"*

Comment: (Per piacere, usate le lettere accentate.)

Answer (score 3):

You could say it like:

"*FIFA ha annunciato ufficialmente un'inchiesta* **la mattina di mercoledì**"

or

"***Mercoledì***, nelle prime ore della **mattinata**".

The best way to say that something happened in the morning of a day, you could say

> La mattina di [Day of week]**...**

Comment: Nota: un parlante nativo direbbe molto probabilmente "*la* FIFA", anche se si sta diffondendo la forma usata da @Charo.

Comment: @TobiaTesan: Non è "la forma usata da Charo", è da Tia27.